# Minimum Height and Width of Facebook Open Graph images?

Tags: facebook, image, facebook-graph-api

I had perused that pictures connected with a given URL in the Facebook open graph must be more prominent than 50 x 50

Nonetheless, when we ran the Facebook Object debugger - we got the accompanying cautioning:

"Tiny og:image: All the images referenced by og:image must be at least 200px in both dimensions. Please check all the images with tag og:image in the given url and ensure that it meets the minimum specification."

Our URL is :- http://lifehacksmag.com and the picture does appear under Object Properties

Do we have to change over our pictures to be more noteworthy then 200 x 200? Alternately would we be able to abandon it as seems to be? It is right now a 65 x 75 picture.

much obliged concerning your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images

> Use images that are at least 1200 x 630 pixels for the best display on high resolution devices. At the minimum, you should use images that are 600 x 315 pixels to display link page posts with larger images.

Forget about the message in the debugger.